# DFT truncation of signals

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, fourier

How can I calculate 8 point DFT of signals whose length is less then 8 ( say 2,4) then what will I assume other members in formulae "0" or rotation or keep repeating the same two numbers

[image]

[image]

[image]

Consider I want to find 4 point DFT of [1,2]

Comment: The DTFT is a formula, a series of exponentials.

Comment: @Stanley Pawlukiewicz Yes it is a formula but if I calculate 8 point DTFT between two signals whose length is less then 8 say 2 then what will I assume other members in formulae 0 or rotation or keep repeating the same two numbers

Comment: I don't think you are looking at the correct formula. N points have N terms

Comment: @Stanley Pawlukiewicz plz see edits

Comment: see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform  one does not repeat or rotate the DTFT

Comment: Buzz, can you learn to do a little $\LaTeX$ math markup instead of scanning a book or paper for images?

Comment: "DTFT between two signals" I'm having trouble understanding what you mean here.

Comment: @MBaz Plz see the edits

Comment: @Stanley Pawlukiewicz  Plz see the edits

Comment: @Buzzbee your question is about the DFT. The DTFT is different, it's a continuous function of frequency

Comment: @Stanley Pawlukiewicz thanks for for pointing out plz see edits